# Scriptcraft location & events

Tags: javascript, events, minecraft, scriptcraft

Hello i'm trying to add events and location to an function so whenever a block is placed on an certain block it gives you a message and adds +1 to the score it doesn't have any errors but it doesn't work I have never programmed in javascript before so.

```js
var score = 0
events.blockPlace( function (event, location) {
if (location.x == -239.538 && location.y == 71.000 && 
location.z ==314.407 ) {
 echo(event.player, 'You have just placed an block');
 var scored = score =+ 1 

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code piece below should work with Spigot and Scriptcraft.

The block position is stored in event.block. The location variable you provided is a method to cancel this event.

The positions provided by the block are integers not floats.

```
var score = 0;
var block_place_event = events.blockPlace(function(event){
    if ((event.block.x == -239) && (event.block.y == 71) && (event.block.z == 314)){
        echo(event.player, 'You have just place an block');
        score = score + 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location for any block event from the block itself

```js
var score = 0
events.blockPlace( function (event) {

  var location = event.block.location

  if (location.x == -239 && location.y == 71 && 
  location.z == 314 ) {
    echo(event.player, 'You have just placed a block');
    var scored = score =+ 1 

  }
});
```

You also will want to cut off any decimal points, since blocks have whole number locations.